# How to only update specific attribute of a record in DataStore amplify

Tags: java, android, kotlin, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-sdk-android

This is my method for `adding/updating` a record on my `Configuration table`

```
public static void saveConfiguration(Configuration model) {
    Amplify.DataStore.save(model,
                success-> logEvent("Configuration added to DataStore"),
                failure -> logErrorEvent("Failed to add configuration in DataStore")
    );
}
```

Amplify Model/Schema:

```
type Configuration @model @auth(rules: [{allow: owner}]) {
id: ID!
name: String
email: String
companyName: String
}
```

For example, I have a record:

| id | name | email | companyName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | Name A | test@gmail.com | Company A |

To update this, I will construct a Configuration model and call `saveConfiguration` method:

```
Configuration amplifyConfiguration = Configuration.builder()
            .name("Name B")
            .email("test@gmail.com")
            .companyName("Company B")
            .id("12345") // primary key
            .build();

saveConfiguration(amplifyConfiguration);
```

The record will be updated to:

| id | name | email | companyName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | Name B | test@gmail.com | Company B |

For some specific scenario, what I want is when I construct a `Configuration` model with updated name only for example, it will only update that column.

```
// updated name only
Configuration amplifyConfiguration = Configuration.builder()
            .name("Name C") 
            .id("12345") // primary key
            .build();

saveConfiguration(amplifyConfiguration);
```

I need the record to be like this:

| id | name | email | companyName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | Name C | test@gmail.com | Company A |

Actual result:

| id | name | email | companyName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | Name C |  |  |

email and companyName is empty since I didn't set any value.